# Your app uses 13 non-SDK interfaces, which are incompatible with Android P+. in android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console

While testing in test lab in firebase get these issues how can I fix it.
Your app uses 13 non-SDK interfaces, which are incompatible with Android P+.

```
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nepLearn.nepLearn"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

[image: check this screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

While violations may be detected on the Firebase Test Lab, it's important to note that these issues might not impact the publishing process on the Play Store. The warnings provided in Firebase Test Lab are advisory and are not necessarily indicative of obstacles during the app's release.